# Converting a Mercurial repo with bookmarks to Git

Tags: windows, git, mercurial

What's the best way to convert a Mercurial repo which uses bookmarks to a Git repo?

I've tried the steps [listed here](http://hedonismbot.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/hg-fast-export-convert-mercurial-repositories-to-git-repositories/) in Cygwin, but it converted only the default branch to master. The "branch" where I am using a bookmark on was not included in the conversion, although it did issue an error at the start about the Hg repo having an "unnamed" head.

The steps [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267232/converting-a-mercurial-hg-repository-to-git-on-windows-7) (using git-hg) did not work at all.

Cygwin has Hg 1.9.3 and Git 1.7.5.1 installed, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurials [hg-git plugin](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git) does the conversion you want. You need to place a bookmark on every revision you want to export to git, and then `hg push /place/to/repo.git` to export the commits.

Comment: The hg-git docs say it can be used for this, but I'm getting [this error](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/520194/) during the conversion, which sounds like a problem with dulwich, according to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hg-git/QiWRNlSJDfM/discussion). Other than this, it would have probably worked, so I'll accept this.