# How to import a Bitbucket project into Github on Windows

Tags: git, mercurial, github, tortoisehg, hg-git

I have a HG project hosted on Bitbucket, and I want to move it to Github.

I have followed the [guideline](http://www.ffuts.org/blog/accessing-a-git-repository-with-tortoisehg-on-windows/) here to install hg-git extension, on my TortoiseHG.

I have created a repository on Github, but have not initialized it yet (it displays that instruction page), so I can't clone that git repository.

What do I go next?

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to add that I will then use git from then on.

UPDATE: I borrowed a mac and converted it using `fast-git-import` painlessly. If anyone tried the solutions below and worked under Windows, vote it up enough, and I'll make it the answer.

Comment: Don't do it - you will suffer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out my question is a duplicate of [Converting a Mercurial (hg) repository to Git on Windows (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267232/converting-a-mercurial-hg-repository-to-git-on-windows-7).

It works well. Since it is all under Cygwin there is no need to use pageant.

In addition to the answer to that question. I just need to generate a key under Cygwin using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. I then copied the content of public key in `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to Github repository setting.

I set the git origin to the Gihub address by `git remote add origin (repo address)`. Then finally I can `git push origin master --force` onto Github.

Answer (score 2):

You should complete the [hg-git process](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgGit) (like an `hg gexport`) locally on your workstation.

Then, when you have a git repo mirroring your initial Hg repo, then you can add a GitHub origin, and push to it:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/yourProject.git
git push origin master
git push --all
```

However, Lazy Badger comments, and rightly so, that the OP might want to only use Mercurial for this process, and not install Git at all.

In which case, the page "[hg-git on GitHub](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git)" contains:

> If you are starting from an existing Hg repository, you have to setup a Git repository somewhere that you have push access to, add it as default path or default-push path in your `.hg/hgrc` and then run `hg push` from within your project.
>   For example:

```
$ cd hg-git # (an Hg repository)
$ # edit .hg/hgrc and add the target git url in the paths section
$ hg push
```

> This will convert all your Hg data into Git objects and push them up to the Git server.

Comment: OP have **Mercurial, not git**

Comment: I tried `hg gexport` but `.git` folder was not created. The link you mentioned doesn't talk about `hg export`. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @LazyBadger: OP has both if he/she wants to convert a Mercurial repo to a git one.

Comment: @lulalala: I was referring to `hg gexport` (`export` was a typo). But my point remains. You do the conversion locally, and then push your newly created repo to your (currently empty) GitHub repo.

Comment: @lulalala: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository for more on the `hg gexport` process.

Comment: @VonC - wrong, I have repo on Github, but use **only Mercurial**. *Never* make decision instead of author, if you aren't shaman or sensitive

Comment: @VonC thanks, but no luck in gexport. Maybe it's because it is answer for Mac

Comment: @LazyBadger: good point (and +1 on your answer).

Answer (score 1):

**In assumption, that base VCS is still Mercurial and tool - TortoiseHG**

1. You have to have ready Git-repo (empty, pushable from local)
2. If you have  added and working (i.e configured properly - can pull|push with Github) hg-git, you have to add Git-URL into (local) repo hgrc ([paths] section)
3. add OpenSSH keys to Github, verify key-based authorisation in THG (pageant)

   - AFAIK, only `git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` URL works for github from hg-git
4. After it you'll have two remote linked repo, for both you'll be able to push/pull from Synchronize tab

**Addons**

Relevant parts from mercurial.ini, git and github related

```
[ui]
...
ssh = "...\TortoisePlink.exe"
...
[auth]
github.com.prefix = github.com
github.com.username = lazybadger
```

Can say nothing about last section, just recall nothing for "when" and "why"

Comment: I created the OpenSSH key using git-bash but can't load it into pageant. I think pageant only loads putty private keys?

Comment: @lulalala - yes, you have to create putty-keypair with Puttygen or import OpenSSH key (?!) into Puttygen and save as putty

Comment: Cool now I have the keys set up, tried to push it in Synchronize: It gave me the error message `creating and sending data
...
[command returned code 255 Mon Feb 20 22:04:23 2012]`

Comment: Do you have pageant with keys running? Check **all** settings according to this check-list [TortoiseHg as a github client on Windows](http://jamesmckay.net/2010/06/tortoisehg-as-a-github-client-on-windows/): I  done all step-by-step and got all functioning without errors

Comment: yes pageant is running, if it is not running it will give a 'pubkey' message. I'll check the doc now.